# Header and footer are being overwritten while creating PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I have  included a cs class for creating the footer and header for a pdf file, so what am getting is the header and footer is overwriting the current contents on the file, what i want is the header to show and shift other cells in every page

```
public  class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper  
    {

        PdfContentByte cb;

        // we will put the final number of pages in a template  
        PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate;

        // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer  
        BaseFont bf = null;

        // This keeps track of the creation time  
        DateTime PrintTime = DateTime.Now;

        #region Fields
        private string _header;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set { _header = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                PrintTime = DateTime.Now;
                bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb = writer.DirectContent;
                headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(100, 100);
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
            }
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
            Font georgia = FontFactory.GetFont("georgia", 10f);
            //iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
            //iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontBig = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
            Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", georgia);

            //Create PdfTable object  
            PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

            iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Content\Images\ArgoGroup.png");
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(myImage);
            pdfTab.DefaultCell.Padding = 4;
            cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;


            String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";
            //Add paging to footer  
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                cb.ShowText(text);
                cb.EndText();
                float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
                cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(180) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
            }
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            cell.Border = 0;

            pdfTab.AddCell(cell);

            pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
            pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;
            //pdfTab.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;      

            //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable  
            //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write  
            //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing  
            pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);
            //set pdfContent value  
        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            headerTemplate.BeginText();
            headerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            headerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            headerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
            headerTemplate.EndText();

            footerTemplate.BeginText();
            footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
            footerTemplate.EndText();
        }
    }
public void createpdf(){



 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

                    writer.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();
                    document.Open();
                    TextReader t = new StringReader(htmlcontent.ToString());
                    HTMLWorker hw = new HTMLWorker(document);
                    hw.Parse(t);
                    document.Close();
                    writer.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `OnEndPage` you explicitly set coordinates for the footer here

```
cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
```

and for the header here

```
pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);
```

If you don't want the footer or header to overlap regular page content, simply choose the coordinates accordingly. Alternatively set the `document` margins to prevent overlapping.

> what i want is the header to show and shift other cells in every page

That's not how itext events work. In `OnEndPage` the regular page content has been layout'ed and is at fixed positions, you merely stamp extras like headers and footers somewhere onto the page, so you have to do that at positions which are unused yet.

Comment: can u please suggest how to change the document top margin so that the header dont get overlapped.

Comment: @RajEevKr *"how to change the document top margin so that the header dont get overlapped"* - you can change the margins in the `Document` constructor with five parameters or using the `Document` method `SetMargins`. I don't know the dimension of your header contents, so I cannot give you concrete values.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
cb = writer.DirectContent;
```

like this

```
public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
    cb = writer.DirectContent;
```

Comment: While your way to write this is clearer than the OP's code, it is not necessary.

Comment: It's more about adding `cb = writer.DirectContent` in the right place.

Comment: But the place used by the OP (in  `OnOpenDocument`) is right, too! The `PdfContentByte` instance you get from `PdfWriter.DirectContent` is special, it always refers to content stream of the the *current* page, you don't need to retrieve it anew after page switch.